# Display orders items names excluding a product category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, taxonomy-terms

With WooCommerce, I have faced a problem on my code below: I have tried skip specific category from my loop. Product has been skipped but some remaining products are showing multiple times:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        if ($product_cat_id != 38355) { //category id
            echo $name = $item->get_name().'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

How can I avoid this item name repetition on this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$product_cat_id` is not defined in your code, so your if statement is always true.

To check for a product category in order items, use instead the [conditional function `has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/). It will avoid getting product name displayed multiple times and items that belong to **`38355`** category ID will be excluded.

Here is your revisited simplified code version:

```
$item_names = array(); // Initializing

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    // Excluding items from a product category term ID
    if ( ! has_term( 38355, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
        $item_names[] = $item->get_name();
    }
}
// Output 
echo implode( '<br>', $item_names );
```

Now it should work as expected